Code Coverage for Nuxtjs using Playwright
Currently Im using Nuxt 3 for my project, and I was wondering if for let's say for end to end testing via Playwright , I can get the code coverage each test.
https://medium.com/@belwalshubham08/nuxt3-cypress-code-coverage-implementation-69c0a5aefda
The only reference that came close was cypress for Nuxt 3, but I couldnt figure out how to do the cofiguration specifically for Playwright,and in the official docs:
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/testing
I've remembered it didint mention anything about cdoe coverage, so do let me know if yall have any thoughts on it or if I'm missing some stuff in these articles.

Not an expert but I am wondering if E2E test coverage is anyhow relevant in such a context. You're trying an actual workflow all along and not a per-line functionality as unit tests would.

@kissu of course its relevant. You still want to know which lines of code are not covered with e2e tests. It doesnt matter if you do unit testing or e2e testing. We are doing a lot of e2e tests in nodejs backend and we use coverage to cover missing parts. We want to do same for frontend nuxt 3 app.
